# Convert datetime to cron expression using quartz api in c#

Tags: c#, cron, quartz

How to convert user selected datetime to cron expression.

Example: User selected datetime as May-31-2017 6:00 PM
Need to convert this datetime to cron expression.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? a cron expression is used to express repetition and here you have a single moment in time.

Comment: Louis, I am trying to create the cron expression based on the use input. Here user can schedule his preferred time to execute the job.

Comment: Louis, I am trying to create the dynamic trigger using quartz , so I am not sure when exactly job should execute. So based on the user selected time  I will create the trigger.